# Mixed derivatives in multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is a function having variables $x$ and $y$. Can $f_{xy}$ at a point be equal to $f_{yx}$ without any of the two being continuous there? If they are equal but discontinuous functions?

Answer (score 0):

The function
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
                     \frac{2x^{2}y}{x^4+y^2} & \mbox{ for } (x, y) \ne (0, 0)\\
                      0                            & \mbox{ for } (x, y) = (0, 0).
                \end{cases}$$

is a good example of a non-continuous function whose partial derivatives all exist.

Answer (score 0):

Let me bring example of differentiable function with discontinuous partial derivatives
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}+y^2 \sin \frac{1}{y}, &\text{  if  }xy\ne 0 \\
x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}, &\text{  if  }x\ne 0,y=0 \\
y^2 \sin \frac{1}{y}, &\text{  if  }y\ne 0,x=0 \\
0 & \text{  if  }y= 0,x=0 
\end{cases}$$
both partial derivatives are discontinuous at point $(0,0)$, but function is differentiable.